# Excel VBA - Creating a ListBox

Tags: excel, vba, listbox

How do you create (not modify/populate) a ListBox in Excel VBA?
I need to generate various ListBoxes for each cell in a column, doing it without VBA would be impractical. I'm looking for something like:

```
Dim lb as ListBox
' Populate ListBox Here '

worksheet.Cells(1,1) = lb ' Apply ListBox to cell '
```

I've googled this thoroughly (maybe my terminology is wrong) but I cant find a single reference to CREATING a listbox, and applying it to various cells.

Thanks!

EDIT: It should be noted that `Dim lb As MSForms.ListBox` throws the error

> "User-defined type not defined"

. Maybe this is how to create ListBoxes... but I need to include this library????? I don't know how to do that though...

Comment: *Each cell in a column should have a listbox* : What data do you want to feed into these *each `listbox`*?And here is [how to create a listbox](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=add+a+listbox+in+vba&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a#hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=QVi&tbo=d&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB%3Aofficial&sclient=psy-ab&q=creating+listbox+vba&oq=creating+listbox+vba&gs_l=serp.3..0i30l4.62752.65494.0.65620.20.15.0.2.2.1.255.2597.0j8j6.14.0.les%3B..0.0...1c.1.tRi2Vh_fxW0&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.41248874,d.bmk&fp=17d56122c46931de&biw=1200&bih=600)

Comment: Can you use Data Validation instead? That typically works for collecting choices on a by-row basis.

Comment: If you actually looked through the Google search your recommended, you'd see there is no explanation on how to create a ListBox purely with VBA.
I must create the ListBoxes purely with VBA. I'm generating a Spreadsheet automatically, the end user should not have to manually insert ListBoxes.

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to create the listbox from Excel, not using VBA, just record one macro with you doing it and then check the resulted code.

LE: This is what i could record. The source values were on the same sheet as the destination list, but i think you can take over from here and expand as needed.

```
With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:="=$A$1:$A$6"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

Comment: The record macro feature is disabled (grayed out). This is because the application was installed without this feature (its a work computer and I cant re-install Excel)

Comment: Can you not find a different machine available?

Comment: Just to be clear, this adds data validation, which acts a lot like a listbox, but isn't a listbox. I think it's probably the way to go though.